# Does C have boolean (True/False)

Tags: c, boolean

Something like this:

```
/*Simple program to calculate the circumference of a circle. */

#include <stdio.h>  
#define PI 3.14159

 int main()

{

  float r1 /*R1 being the radius.*/
  /* Since the Circumference is R * PI * 2, or R2 * PI */
  /* we do the following */

  printf("This is a program that calculates the Circumference\n");
  printf("Of a circle. Please enter your radius.\n");

   scanf("%f", r1"\n"); /*This being the first number.*/
  printf("Your radius times PI times 2 is\n");
  /*Now it calculates the circumference. */

   printf("%f", (r1 * PI * 2)"\n");

}
```

I would also be doing mathematical stuff using C,so any lowdown on that  would help as well. For example,I wonder if I can `#define` **Pi** as a number, or any constant of that nature, and then use  it in a True/False statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "#define PI as a number [...], and have it as a TRUE/FALSE statement" - 1. not a statement, an expression. 2. What's a "boolean function"? 3. How do you want to use PI as true/false?

Comment: I guess I wrote the questions wrong, not a Boolean function, but just a Boolean in general, so define PI as a number, then have a True/False after that? I apologize for asking the question wrong.

Comment: Pi is already defined in `<math.h>` as `M_PI`, don't define it. Also, what do you mean by "having a true/false after Pi"?

Comment: the code does not compile, is not consistently indented, and is mostly irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: I want to use PI as in, if someone doesn't type in PI, or 3.14159, then it will return back with something along the lines of "That is not PI" or how ever you might say it.

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite So basically you're asking for `if (someNumber != PI)`? Then have a look at comparison operators.

Comment: Yeah. Pretty much. I am quite the beginner, so I couldn't think of any syntax that would give the idea of my question, so I tried to explain it as best as I could and apologize for any inconvenience it brought anyone. @Elazar

Comment: @H2CO3 yeah, that's practically what I'm asking, and I'm just a learner here, so I apologize for any confusion as to what my question was. I almost sound stupid the way I asked it.

Comment: @MarkusAndrewWhite A piece of good advice: try to learn C from some kind of complete guide/tutorial/paper/book. Sorry to say that, but this question is indeed very bad (and you also seem to be having problems with formulating your questions in a reasonably good English.) Stack Overflow's principal purpose is not to teach beginners a language completely, it's suited for helping others to solve a specific programming problem. Learning an entire language isn't specific enough.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks a lot! I'll definitely keep that in mind next time I ask a question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a boolean datatype in the latest version of C. And you can create them with an enum. But I think you mean something like this

```
int v=42;
if(v) printf("hi there\n");
v=0;
if(v) printf("hi there\n");
if(! v) printf("hi there\n");
v=42;
if(! v) printf("hi there\n");
```

This works with integer data types.  In the example - if v ==0 then (! v) returns true and (v) returns false. When v is non-zero (including negative numbers) then ! v) returns false and (v) returns true.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm trying to get at, sometimes my questions can become broad. So I could use if statements to make sure it's True/False?

Comment: PI is not true or false, not conceptually, if you say hey, PI != 0 so PI is true, makes no sense

Comment: Aaah I gotcha on that one. Thanks @DGomez

Answer (score 2):

0 is equivalent to FALSE. Anything else is TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but you have to include a header file to use bool datatypes

```
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
  bool arr[2] = {true, false};
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum boolean {false = 0, true};
```

Perhaps you tried to say something like:

```
if(PI*someRadius == someNumber);//...
```

then yes..., you can do that